# An error in launching my custom world into Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

- In the tutorial of **Ros
  integration**
  http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models
- using the following command

  > ```
  > . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
  > roslaunch MYROBOT_gazebo MYROBOT.launch
  > ```
- I had the following error

> ```
> >     [MYROBOT.launch] is neither a launch file in package
> > [MYROBOT_gazebo] nor is [MYROBOT_gazebo] a launch file name
> ```

- my distribution is **Hydro**
- I use **ubuntu 12.10**

*any help,please*

*****Thanks in advance*****

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5489/an-error-in--launching-my-custom-world--into-gazebo/) by [Eman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/624/eman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2014-02-17**:
Have you run catkin_make in that workspace before launching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This indicates some kind of problem with your workspace setup. Either your "MYROBOT_gazebo" package could not be found, or your "MYROBOT_gazebo" package could be found, but not the "MYROBOT.launch" launch file inside it. To find out what is happening, you can try

```
roscd MYROBOT_gazebo
```

If get a "no such package/stack" error, the package could not be found.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/624/eman/) on 2014-02-18**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher Thanks very much for your help. God bless you. I tried the command " roscd MYROBOT_gazebo " & I found the error that you mentioned ( roscd: No such package/stack 'MYROBOT_gazebo' ) . what should I do if the package are not found? Should I remove the catkin_WS & then recreate it & recreate the package?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-18**:
This means you either made a mistake when following the tutorial, or there is an error in the tutorial. I´d suggest re-doing the tutorial and taking extra care not to miss anything. Hopefully that solves the problem, otherwise report back. Note that MYROBOT_gazebo should be replaced with your own package name, for example "eman_robot_gazebo". It seems the tutorial also requires some basic knowledge of how catkin and ROS work.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/624/eman/) on 2014-02-18**:
Thanks a lot for your help. God bless you. Thanks also for your suggestion. I will re-do the tutorial with care of every thing & confirm basic knowledge of how catkin and ROS work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have you run catkin_make in that workspace before launching?

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/624/eman/) on 2014-02-18**:
Thanks for your help. God bless you.                                                                                           No,I have not run  catkin_make in that workspace before launching.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2014-02-18**:
Then try to run it and try to roslaunch again!  I think the build process somehow alerts ROS to the presence of the package.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/624/eman/) on 2014-02-21**:
Thanks a lot for your help. The problem had been solved.